# 404 page returns 200 ok

Tags: .htaccess, error-handling, http-status-code-404

If i type www.mydomain/error404.html directly in to browser bar should it return a 404 responce or 200 ok?

if i type www.mydomain.co.uk/something-that-dosent-exist.html, it returns the 404 page with the correct status as 404, however should my actual 404.html page return 200ok??

http://gsitecrawler.com/tools/Server-Status.aspx

domain http://www.novahealthy.co.uk

error doc  error404.html

---

htaccess

```
AddType x-mapp-php4 .htm

#turn off the smart spelling matching feature.
CheckSpelling off

#set your real error document, which can be a php document.
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

---

host is 1and1 shared hosting

cheers for any help lee

Comment: Well, what do you want it to return? You can set the returned status using the `header` function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct.  If you're going to any world-accessible site and your browser successfully gets that page you should have 200 OK returned.

Typically you don't keep error pages in a place that a user is able to directly access.  You usually internally redirect to an error page on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to return a 200. Your page (even though it's named 404, and is being used as your redirect 404 page) exists, and it was found and served correctly.